# Route Attribute not working in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have two `GET` methods on my API controller. When I attempt to call the `GetByCompanyId` method, which I have decorated with the Route Attribute, the request instead is being routed to the `GetById` method.  Below are the relevant code files.

**global.ascx.cs**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

**webApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.EnableCors();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

**route.config**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**CompanyFunctionsController.cs**

```
public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
{
    var companyFunction = this._service.GetByKey(new object[] { id });

    if (companyFunction != null)
    {
        var companyFunctionDto = Mapper.Map<CompanyFunctionDto>(companyFunction);

        return Ok(companyFunctionDto);
    }

    return NotFound();
}

[Route("CompanyFunctions/GetByCompanyId", Name = "GetByCompanyId")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<CompanyFunctionDto> GetByCompanyId(int id)
{
    var collection = this._service.GetAll().ToList().Where(x => x.CompanyId == id);

    IEnumerable<CompanyFunctionDto> collectCompanyFunctionDtos = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyFunctionDto>>(collection);

    return collectCompanyFunctionDtos;
}
```

**My HTTP request:**
http://localhost:1317/api/CompanyFunctions/GetByCompanyId?id=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a route that starts with `api` like `http://localhost:1317/api/CompanyFunctions/GetByCompanyId?id=1` then you must use the string `api` in your route attribute that you want it to go to.

```
[Route("api/CompanyFunctions/GetByCompanyId", Name = "GetByCompanyId")]
```

Otherwise it will only match based on the http verb (Get in this case).

Alternatively you can decorate the web api controller with the `[RoutePrefix("api/CompanyFunctions")]` attribute as well and change your Route attribute to `[Route("GetByCompanyId", Name = "GetByCompanyId")]`

Comment: Thanks Igor, that was the problem, I didn't have the `api`!

Answer (score 3):

Web API 2 supports a new type of routing, called attribute routing. As the name implies, attribute routing uses attributes to define routes. Attribute routing gives you more control over the URIs in your web API
You might use Attribute Routing in Web Api to solve your problems. Your Controller Action should be like this,

```
    [Route("CompanyFunctions/GetByCompanyId/{companyId}"]
 public IEnumerable<CompanyFunctionDto> GetByCompanyId(int companyId)
 {
    var collection = this._service.GetAll().ToList().Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId);

    IEnumerable<CompanyFunctionDto> collectCompanyFunctionDtos = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyFunctionDto>>(collection);

    return collectCompanyFunctionDtos;
 }
```

and your HTTP request is http://localhost:1317/CompanyFunctions/GetByCompanyId/1

Comment: Thanks Safal, I ended up tacking on that {companyId} (althought I made it {id} on the end.  That helped! :)